# check if delete was successful message php ajax jquery mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

hi guys even i have success delete the message return false delete message("could not delete") besides success delete messege but query is wokrking 
please tell me what i am doing wrong here is my codes \

delete.php

```
  if(isset($_POST['delete_id']) && !empty($_POST['delete_id'])) {
          $delete_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['delete_id']);
    $query=mysql_query("DELETE FROM color WHERE idColor='$delete_id'");
    if($query != false) {
            echo 'true';
          }
    mysql_close();
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.del_btn').click(function(){
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Color?"))
       var del_id = $(this).attr('rel');
              $.post('script/delete_color.php', {delete_id:del_id}, function(data) {
          if(data == 'true') {
            $('#'+del_id).remove();alert('Color has been deleted!');
          }
           else {
            alert('Color could not delete!');
          }
                document.messages.submit();
            return false; // This line added}
    });
    }); 
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really understand your problem, but I'm going to take an educated guess...

You need to wrap your logic inside the "confirm" IF statement.  Also, you had an extra "});".

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.del_btn').click(function() {

        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Color?")) {

            var del_id = $(this).attr('rel');

            $.post('script/delete_color.php', {delete_id:del_id}, function(data) {

                if(data == 'true') {
                    $('#'+del_id).remove();alert('Color has been deleted!');
                } else {
                    alert('Color could not delete!');
                }

                document.messages.submit();
                return false; // This line added
            }
        }
    });
});
```